# Using the SPLIT_TO_TABLE function conditionally

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm using SPLIT_TO_TABLE to split a column which has multiple comma separated values

The input table looks like this:

[image]

I'm using the following query:

```
SELECT ID,DATE_KEY,COUNTRY, y.value AS new_sub
FROM TABLE, LATERAL split_to_table(TABLE.SUBDIVISIONS, ', ') y
```

Which results in the following output:

[image]

I want to have the rows that have NULL subdivision also included in the output.

Is there a way to conditionally use the function to just apply when the column is a non null value or would it be better to just join two outputs (one where subdivision is null and the result of my query)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `STRTOK_TO_ARRAY()` to convert SUBDIVISION into an ARRAY and then use a Lateral Flatten with `outer => TRUE`

```
with tt as ( Select * 
FROM (VALUES
(98,TO_DATE('1/01/2020','DD/MM/YY'),'DE',NULL),
(99,TO_DATE('6/01/2020','DD/MM/YY'),'DE','DE,DE-BY,DE-ST'),
(100,TO_DATE('8/03/2020','DD/MM/YY'),'DE','DE_BE'),
(101,TO_DATE('20/03/2020','DD/MM/YY'),'DE',NULL)
) AS tt (ID, DATE_KEY, COUNTRY, SUBDIVISIONS ) )

SELECT ID,DATE_KEY,COUNTRY, y.value AS new_sub
FROM TT, LATERAL FLATTEN ( INPUT => STRTOK_TO_ARRAY(TT.SUBDIVISIONS, ','), OUTER => TRUE) y;
```

Comment: Yes, this gives me the desired output. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could make `split_to_table` preserve `nulls` by assigning your delimiter `','` to subdivisions when they are `null` using `coalesce`. If you prefer `null` instead of blanks, you can use `nullif` in the outer `select`

```
select id, date_key, country, nullif(y.value,'') as new_sub
from t, lateral split_to_table( coalesce(t.subdivisions,',') , ', ') y
```